# Automate conversion of SQL query to python code

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to create a Python script which can convert the SQL query into a Python script using a regex. Can someone throw some ideas to achieve this in Python?

```
============SQL Query========
SELECT
   alert_id,
   Count(star_rating) as total_rating,
   Max(star_rating) AS best_rating,
   Min(star_rating) AS worst_rating 
FROM
   alerts 
WHERE
   verified_purchase = 'Y' 
   AND review_date BETWEEN '1995-07-22' AND '2015-08-31' 
   AND country IN 
   (
      'DE','US','UK','FR','JP' 
   )
GROUP BY
   alert_id 
ORDER BY
   total_rating asc,
   alert_id desc,
   best_rating 
LIMIT 10;
```

Below are the expected result:

```
alerts.filter("verified_purchase = 'Y' AND review_date BETWEEN '1995-07-22' AND '2015-08-31' AND country IN ('DE', 'US', 'UK', 'FR', 'JP')")
.groupBy("alert_id")
.agg(count(col("star_rating")).alias('total_rating'),max(col("star_rating")).alias('best_rating'),min(col("star_rating")).alias('worst_rating')")
.select("alert_id","total_rating","best_rating","worst_rating")
.orderBy(col("total_rating").asc(),col("alert_id").desc(),col("best_rating").asc())
.limit(10)
```

Comment: ===code so far i have developed===
from tika import parser
import re

filename = '/home/linux/sqlfile.txt'

# Parse the text
parsedtext = parser.from_file(filename)

# Extract the text content from the parsed txt
txt = parsedtxt["content"]

# Convert doublelines into single
txt = txt.replace('\n', '')

#####################################
# Do something with the txt
#####################################
print (txt)

Comment: `
===code so far i have developed===
from tika import parser
import re

filename = '/home/linux/sqlfile.txt'

# Parse the text
parsedtext = parser.from_file(filename)

# Extract the text content from the parsed txt
txt = parsedtxt["content"]

# Convert doublelines into single
txt = txt.replace('\n', '')

#####################################
# Do something with the txt
#####################################
print (txt)

`

Comment: ============result so far i have achieved=========
`>>> print(txt)
    SELECT   alert_id,   Count(star_rating) as total_rating,   Max(star_rating) AS best_rating,   Min(star_rating) AS worst_rating FROM   alerts WHERE   verified_purchase = 'Y'    AND review_date BETWEEN '1995-07-22' AND '2015-08-31'    AND country IN    (      'DE','US','UK','FR','JP'    )GROUP BY   alert_id ORDER BY   total_rating asc,   alert_id desc,   best_rating LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Why would you do this?  All SQL adapters allow you to make SQL queries directly.  This seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a project that does it for SQLAlchemy code.

https://github.com/pglass/sqlitis

It seems that feature matrix is incomplete, but it's open source, so it may be better to contribute to the project than writing from scratch (and it seems like a fun and active project).

Definitely don't use regex. I recomment classic SO answer why not: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)